# Splitting comma separated values into rows - Data Cleaning

Tags: python, excel

[image]

How to split a column into rows if values are separated with a comma? I am stuck in here. I have used the following code

```
xd = df.assign(var1=df['var1'].str.split(',')).explode('var1')
xd = xd.assign(var2=xd['var2'].str.split(',')).explode('var2')
xd
```

But the above code generate multiple irrelevant rows. I am stuck here. Please suggest answers

Answer (score 1):

**DataFrame.explode**

For multiple columns, specify a non-empty list with each element be str or tuple, and all specified columns their list-like data on same row of the frame must have matching length.

From [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[0, 1, 2], 'foo', [], [3, 4]],
                   'B': 1,
                   'C': [['a', 'b', 'c'], np.nan, [], ['d', 'e']]})
df
           A  B          C
0  [0, 1, 2]  1  [a, b, c]
1        foo  1        NaN
2         []  1         []
3     [3, 4]  1     [d, e]
```

Multi-column explode.

```
df.explode(list('AC'))
     A  B    C
0    0  1    a
0    1  1    b
0    2  1    c
1  foo  1  NaN
2  NaN  1  NaN
3    3  1    d
3    4  1    e
```

For your specific question:

```
xd = df.assign(
    var1=df['var1'].str.split(','),
    var2=df['var2'].str.split(',')
).explode(['var1', 'var2'])
xd
    var1    var2    var3
0   a   e   1
0   b   f   1
0   c   g   1
0   d   h   1
1   p   s   2
1   q   t   2
1   r   u   2
```

Comment: Oh Oh was doing the same without nesting. silly mistake. Thanks @fariaseduv